# Change in adress in between blue card delivery

Tags: germany, blue-card

I want to apply for blue card , there are chances that i will change my apartment before my blue card delievered to my current apartment . I am not sure about my future apartment yet . So is there a way to handle this situation

Comment: Did you know: This site features a [search function](/search/). See comments in [Updating BlueCard address mid-application](/q/24019), [My Address will be changed soon and I have not received my Blue Card yet -Germany](/q/21940) and possibly other questions.